# Getting SUM() from multiple tables with conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I am trying to get the `due_amount` from two tables that is invoices and offline_invoice.
The condition is; `status not like 'paid%'`. I am working with this query

```
select 
    (sum(i.total_amount) + sum(oi.invoice_amount)) - (sum(i.paid_amount) + sum(oi.paid_amount)) due_amount
from
    {CI}invoices i
        left join
    {CI}offline_invoice oi ON oi.customer_id = i.customer_id
where
    i.customer_id = ?
        and i.status not like 'paid%'
group by i.customer_id
```

But i don't know how do i use condition on joined table({CI}offline_invoice)? I have to use the same condition(`status not like 'paid%'`) on it.

Comment: a.status = b.status and a.status not like 'Paid%'

Comment: I think a left join is not correct to get what you want

Comment: @vidaica Please tell me any other alternative if you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the and to the ON clause too

```
   left join
    {CI}offline_invoice oi ON oi.customer_id = i.customer_id
       AND oi.status not like 'paid%'
where
    i.customer_id = ?
        and i.status not like 'paid%'
```

However, I'm not sure how this is going to work for you without possible Cartesian impact.  Say you have 10 current invoice and 10 and 6 offline invoices.  I would do two separate pre-aggregates joined by their customer ID... unless the off-line invoice has the same invoice ID as current (such as archive purposes)

```
select 
      CurInvoices.Customer_ID,
      CurInvoices.InvBalance + COALESCE( OIInvoices.OIBalance, 0 ) as AllBalanceDue
   from
      ( select i.customer_id,
               sum( i.total_amount - i.paid_amount ) as invBalance
           from
              {CI}invoices i
           where
                  i.customer_id = ?
              and i.status not like 'paid%'
           group by
              i.customer_ID ) as CurInvoices
      LEFT JOIN 
      ( select oi.customer_id,
               sum( oi.total_amount - oi.paid_amount ) as OIBalance
           from
              {CI}offline_invoice oi
           where
                  oi.customer_id = ?
              and oi.status not like 'paid%' 
           group by
              i.customer_ID ) as OIInvoces
         on CurInvoices.Customer_ID = OIInvoices.customer_ID
```

Comment: I am getting `NULL` after including the AND condition :(

Comment: @jogesh_pi, added other query that may help with Cartesian issues.